# How to limit my scoreboard to 100 top Score then adding the number list?

Tags: unity, leaderboards

so I want to make 100 top scorers on my leaderboard but I don't know how to make a number list, what I mean is when the user is top 1 so number list 1 and so on

so here the leaderboard script :

```cs
 public IEnumerator LoadScoreboardData()
    {
        var DBTask = DBreference.Child("users").OrderByChild("highscore").LimitToLast(100).GetValueAsync();

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

        if (DBTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
        }
        else
        {
            //Data has been retrieved
            DataSnapshot snapshot = DBTask.Result;

            //Destroy any existing scoreboard elements
            foreach (Transform child in _MainMenuUI.instance.scoreboardContent.transform)
            {
                Destroy(child.gameObject);
            }

            //Loop through every users UID
            foreach (DataSnapshot childSnapshot in snapshot.Children.Reverse<DataSnapshot>())
            {
                string username = childSnapshot.Child("username").Value.ToString();
                int highscore = int.Parse(childSnapshot.Child("highscore").Value.ToString());

                //Instantiate new scoreboard elements
                GameObject scoreboardElement = Instantiate(_MainMenuUI.instance.scoreElement, _MainMenuUI.instance.scoreboardContent);
                scoreboardElement.GetComponent<_ScoreElementContent>().NewScoreElement(username, highscore);
            }

            //Go to scoreboard screen
            _MainMenuUI.instance.leaderboardPanel.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```

[image]

as you can see there is no number list just order by highest score.

Comment: You are creating already the name/ points in a loop in your ui, ordered by the score. What prevents you from adding a counter in the first row that adds a "." behind it to get your 1. MyName MyScore

Comment: @Zibelas sorry I don't understand

Comment: @Zibelas like increment counter?

Comment: yes, a simple counter in your loop since the result is already ordered